# SQL - Subtract values in 2 columns - Add to new column

Tags: sql

*** EDIT ***

Got the original code working now thanks to some help from some great users on here!

```
 SELECT 
               STOCK.STOCK_CODE As Stock_Code,
               STOCK.SHORT_DESC As Stock_Description,
               STOCK.AVAILABILITY As Available, 
               SUM(SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD) As Quantity_Sold,
               ABS(CAST(STOCK.AVAILABILITY AS INT) - CAST(SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD AS INT)) AS ACTUAL
FROM 
    STOCK INNER JOIN SORDER_ITEM ON STOCK.STOCK_ID=SORDER_ITEM.STOCK_ID
GROUP BY SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD, STOCK.STOCK_CODE, STOCK.SHORT_DESC, STOCK.AVAILABILITY
```

I've done a GROUP BY but the data still comes out as such:

```
5000A   TShirt  107 28  93
5000A   TShirt  107 21  86
5000A   TShirt  107 14  100
```

However it should read:

```
5000A TShirt - 107 63 44
```

SAMPLE DATA *
SQL RETURNS:

```
5000A   Tshirt  107 28  93
5000A   Tshirt  107 21  86
5000A   Tshirt  107 14  100
```

STOCK

```
5000A - TSHIRT - 107
```

SORDER_ITEM

```
5000A - TSHIRT - 28
5000A - TSHIRT - 21
5000A - TSHIRT - 14
```

Comment: somewhere you have a non-numeric character in a varchar column.  check your table definitions first - then maybe sort those columns DESC to look for funny characters.

Comment: Don't store numbers in string columns.  They are prone to generating errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error clearly states, one of the fields you are subtracting is in varchar. Try casting it to an integer

```
 SELECT 
               STOCK.STOCK_CODE As Stock_Code,
               STOCK.SHORT_DESC As Stock_Description,
               STOCK.AVAILABILITY As Available, 
               SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD As Quantity_Sold,
               ABS(CAST(STOCK.AVAILABILITY AS INT) - CAST(SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD AS INT)) AS ACTUAL
FROM 
    STOCK INNER JOIN SORDER_ITEM ON STOCK.STOCK_ID=SORDER_ITEM.STOCK_ID
```

If it still doesnt fix your problem, there might be bad data in your fields i.e. some alphabet or special character. Try sorting as descending and check if all are proper numbers in the field.

EDIT - Use sum for the Availability field too

```
SELECT 
               STOCK.STOCK_CODE As Stock_Code,
               STOCK.SHORT_DESC As Stock_Description,
               SUM(STOCK.AVAILABILITY) As Available, 
               SUM(SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD) As Quantity_Sold,
               ABS(CAST(SUM(STOCK.AVAILABILITY) AS INT) - CAST(SUM(SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD) AS INT)) AS ACTUAL
FROM 
    STOCK INNER JOIN SORDER_ITEM ON STOCK.STOCK_ID=SORDER_ITEM.STOCK_ID
GROUP BY STOCK.STOCK_CODE, STOCK.SHORT_DESC
```

Comment: You are welcome, if your problem is solved close the question by marking it as answered.

Comment: Thanks, this seem's to working, just checking the data now!

Comment: Ok, so I now worked out why the data was't adding up.  There are numerous QTY_SOLD's which need to all be added together and the minused from the one STOCK_AVAILABLE field.  Is this done using GROUP BY?

Comment: Yes, a group by would help to summarize the data but remember you can select only the fields which you are using in the group by clause.

Comment: Hi, excuse my ignorance, but am still struggling to get this right. Here is the SQL code I have added: 
****** GROUP BY SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD, STOCK.STOCK_CODE, STOCK.SHORT_DESC, STOCK.AVAILABILITY ******However it only sums the numbers that were the same, it doesn't total the QTY_SOLD column as expected.

Comment: Hmm ok different error now! It says the Operand data varchar is invalid for SUM operator. Do I need to cast as an int again? Apologies for this, sadly I didn't create this database no idea why they set quantities as VARCHAR.

Comment: Just edited main thread with sample data but it's awaiting peer review.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help!! But it must be the data in the table is funny as still getting the error about OPERAND DATA VARCHAR IS INVALID FOR SUM OPERATOR.

Comment: I tested the sample values which you provided and it worked well. Check for any problem with the data.

Comment: Yeah I just made those up based on the data in the table.  There are lots of fields in both tables so wouldn't make sense posting them both.  I've tried using CAST AS INT and convert with both the sum fields yet it still says the same error about the sum.  I'm completely stuck here sadly.

Comment: Try these statements, 

SELECT AVAILABILITY FROM STOCK. ORDER BY DESC

SELECT QTY_SOLD FROM SORDER_ITEM. ORDER BY DESC.

Look at the top most and bottom most values. If there is any issue with the data, you would find it by this approach

Comment: Ok, it looks like the availability sometimes had null values.  Not even a 0.  So have added a WHERE STOCK.AVAILABILITY > 0 but it is still not properly grouping the QTY SOLD column.  There are 2 identical stock codes, with identical availability and different QTY_SOLD.

Comment: Did u try my edited code. It just needs stock_code and short_desc to be same

Comment: I did, it gives the error: Column: STOCK.AVAILABILITY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP by clause.

Comment: My bad, didnt include the computed column properly. Check now

Comment: If I use your code as is I get the VARCHAR error again. So I converted the AVAILABLE column and then get the Column STOCK AVAILABILITY is invalid in the select list again.  Just to clarify I don't need to SUM the available column I just need one record which sums the QTY_SOLD and then works out AVAILABLE - QTY_SOLD.

Comment: Glad I was able to help ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you write :

```
STOCK.AVAILABILITY - SORDER_ITEM.QTY_SOLD
```

one of them is not a numeric type. You need to convert it to a numeric type before you can use it in an arithmetic repression. 
See the conversion logic here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396